# syntax error at insert into

Tags: ms-access, vba

i need to insert some informations from a form to a table fields, i tried this code:

```
Dim sql As String

sql = " insert into récapRELAIS( Région, Groupe, Agence, N°personne, 
    Nom du client, N°prêt, Durée, Nature du prêt, Encours client) 
    Values (" 
    & Me.Region & "  , " & Me.Groupe & " , " 
    & Me.Agence & " , " & Me.Num_Personne & " , " 
    & Me.Nom_client & " , " & Me.Num_Contrat & " , " 
    & Me.Montant_prêt & ", " & Me.Durée_prêt & " ," 
    & Me.Nature_prêt & " , " & Me.Encours & "); "

DoCmd.RunSQL sql
```

but it doesn't work, it says that i have an error type 3134

Comment: Please use the editor to format the code. It will be much more readable and it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are most likely your field names with spaces.

**Solution:** Surround with square brackets - `[ ]`, like this:

```
insert into récapRELAIS( Région, Groupe, Agence, [N°personne], 
[Nom du client], [N°prêt], Durée, [Nature du prêt], [Encours client])
```

I am also not sure if the `°` sign is working.

In general, I advice you to not take spaces or special characters or diacritics like `ê è é` for database field names.

Formatting and pretty display should take place in the user interface; but the database is more a programming environment, and there, it's better to just use the basic characters `A-Z` and `0-9`.

Comment: thank you it works now, i changed the special characters :)

Comment: @SaraKannaoui mark as answer if this has answered your question.